# An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I am trying to fetch the data using joins but it shows error when I get the `ParentHireGroupName`. It works fine when i do comment that line of code!

**Function**

```
public IList<RptFleetHireGroupDetail> GetFleetReport()
        {
            var fleetHireGroupDetailQuery = from vehicle in DbSet                
                join hgd in db.HireGroupDetails on
                    new {ModelID = vehicle.VehicleModelId, MakeID = vehicle.VehicleMakeId, CategoryId = vehicle.VehicleCategoryId, Year= vehicle.ModelYear }
                    equals new { ModelID = hgd.VehicleMakeId, MakeID = hgd.VehicleMakeId, CategoryId = hgd.VehicleCategoryId, Year = hgd.ModelYear }
                select new RptFleetHireGroupDetail
                {
                    HireGroupName = hgd.HireGroup.HireGroupName,
                    PlateNumber = vehicle.PlateNumber,
                    ParentHireGroupName = hgd.HireGroup.ParentHireGroup!=null? "kuch to hai":string.Empty,

                };
            return fleetHireGroupDetailQuery.OrderBy(fhgd => fhgd.FleetPoolName).ToList();
        }
```

**RptFleetHireGroupDetail**

```
public class RptFleetHireGroupDetail
    {
        #region Public
        public string HireGroupName { get; set; }
        public string ParentHireGroupName { get; set; }
        public string PlateNumber { get; set; }
        #endregion
}
```

**Additional error info :**
*`Cannot compare elements of type 'HireGroup'. Only primitive types, enumeration types and entity types are supported.`*

Comment: Following link explains the error and resolutions. Although the scenario may be different in both the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15592042/linq-to-entities-only-primitive-types-or-enumeration-types-are-supported-error

Comment: M using linq to sql!