# NotSupportedException when use FirstOrDefault in Any() clause

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I use the following LINQ query to get user id and document path from my database.

> ```
> var usr = DB.tbl_user
>     .Where(x => x.Account.Contains(user))
>     .ToList()
>     .FirstOrDefault();
>
> var _obj = (from tbl_pld_doc in DB.tbl_pld_doc
>             where tbl_pld_doc.path != null
>             where tbl_pld_doc.Item.Contains(doc)
>             where tbl_pld_doc.tbl_roles.Any(x => x.Id == usr.tbl_roles.FirstOrDefault().Id)
>             select tbl_pld_doc).ToList();
> ```

Unfortunately I got error message:

> An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Unable to create a constant value of type
>   'WebApplicationTestDb.Models.tbl_roles'. Only primitive types or
>   enumeration types are supported in this context.

But when I  use a variable `usr_role_id` to temporary store the `usr.tbl_roles.FirstOrDefault().Id`, everything works fine.

> ```
> var usr = DB.tbl_user
>     .Where(x => x.Account.Contains(user))                                
>     .ToList()
>     .FirstOrDefault();
>
> var usr_role_id = usr.tbl_roles.FirstOrDefault().Id;
>
> var _obj = (from tbl_pld_doc in DB.tbl_pld_doc
>             where tbl_pld_doc.path != null
>             where tbl_pld_doc.Item.Contains(doc)
>             where tbl_pld_doc.tbl_roles.Any(x => x.Id == usr_role_id )
>             select tbl_pld_doc).ToList();
> ```

My question is: why these two cases have different behavior?

Comment: Did you try searching? You need to extract `usr.tbl_roles.FirstOrDefault().Id` into a separate variable and pass _that_ to the second query, like you do in the second example. What is your question?

Comment: Apart from anything else, calling `FirstOrDefault().SomeProperty` is basically saying "I'm okay with getting a NullReferenceException".

Comment: @CodeCaster that's what he does in the second approach - have you read the question entirely?

Comment: @Toshi yes, so what's the question?

Comment: @CodeCaster obviousy why this behaves different

Comment: In the first case the query analyzer is attempting to convert `usr.tbl_roles.FirstOrDefault().Id` into SQL and it fails. In the second case you are doing a simple comparison with a GUID which the query analyzer does know how to convert to SQL.

Comment: @Toshi there's nothing "obvious" here, we shouldn't be guessing at what the OP is asking. Perhaps you and the OP should read [ask].

Comment: @CodeCaster, it seems clear to me that OP asked: "why does the query succeed with a temporary variable that stores `usr.tbl_roles.FirstOrDefault().Id`, and instead without it the query fails?".

Comment: @MassimilianoKraus like I said, read [ask] and don't guess at what a question is supposed to ask. "It seems clear to me" still leaves room for interpretation. Is it that hard to understand that we need clear questions here?

Comment: @CodeCaster, Sorry, my question is not clear enough. I'm just curious to know why these two cases have different behaviors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your cases have different behavior due to limitation of the data provider you are using, some of them may be able to handle complex queries like yours and some cannot.

The error happens when your query is being translated from LINQ to database query language i.e. SQL in your case. In the second case you are reducing and pre-calculating part of the query before the translation step is taking place and replacing it with the constant instead. Data provider can translate it now with no issue. Hope it helps to understand it better.

Here is another answer to the same problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/15592157/920557.